# How to write a function similar to split()

Tags: python, function, cpython

In my online PCAP learning course, this question is asked:
*You already know how split() works. Now we want you to prove it.
Your task is to write your own function, which behaves almost exactly like the original split() method, i.e.:*

- *it should accept exactly one argument - a string;*
- *it should return a list of words created from the string, divided in the places where the string contains whitespaces;*
- *if the string is empty, the function should return an empty list;*
- *its name should be mysplit()*

The skeleton given is:

```
def mysplit(strng):
    #
    # put your code here
    #


print(mysplit("To be or not to be, that is the question"))
print(mysplit("To be or not to be,that is the question"))
print(mysplit("   "))
print(mysplit(" abc "))
print(mysplit(""))
```

and the expected output is:

```
['To', 'be', 'or', 'not', 'to', 'be,', 'that', 'is', 'the', 'question']
['To', 'be', 'or', 'not', 'to', 'be,that', 'is', 'the', 'question']
[ ]
['abc']
[ ]
```

This is the code I came up with:

```
def mysplit(strng):
        A = ""
        B = []
        for i in strng:
                if i != " ":
                        A += i
                        
                else:
                        B.append(A)
                        A = ""

        return(B)
                        
print(mysplit("To be or not to be, that is the question"))
print(mysplit("To be or not to be,that is the question"))
print(mysplit("   "))
print(mysplit(" abc "))
print(mysplit(""))
```

BUT! My output is sooooo close, yet I'm not sure why is ("question") not in there, and why the supposed empty lists has [" "] in them...

```
['To', 'be', 'or', 'not', 'to', 'be,', 'that', 'is', 'the']
['To', 'be', 'or', 'not', 'to', 'be,that', 'is', 'the']
['', '', '']
['', 'abc']
[]
```

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Whenever the `strng` is iterated fully, `A` may contain the last word (in your case `question`). This needs to be added to the list `B`. Also in else you may need to check if `A` is a valid string before appending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

1. You're not appending the last word to `B`, because you only append when you encounter a space, and there's no space at the end of the string. So you need to append the last word.
2. When there are multiple spaces in a row, each one causes you to append the empty `A` to the result. You should only append `A` if it's not empty.

```
def mysplit(strng):
    A = ""
    B = []
    for i in strng:
        if i != " ":
            A += i
        elif A != "":
            B.append(A)
            A = ""
    # Append last word
    if A != "":
        B.append(A)

    return(B)
```

Answer (score 0):

After you've looked at last character, there isn't an additional `" "` that will make you `append` the last word that you've found, so the last word ("question") isn't added.

One way to fix this is the add another check after your `for` loop to see if you need to add the last word.

Comment: great pointer, I'll watch out for that next time

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your string is `X Y`. You loop over `strng`. When you encounter `" "` you append `X` in the list. Then you iterate over `Y` and `A` becomes `Y`. Then the loop terminates. So, the `Y` never added to the list.

To fix this, after the loop is over, just check whether `A` contains a valid (non-empty) string. If yes, append. If the last character of your string is a whitespace, the in that case after loop termination `A` will hold empty string and it will not be added to the list.

For the other problem, `" abc "` or `"   "`, before you append to list- you might want to check `A` if it is non-empty string or not.

Try this -

```
def mysplit(strng):
    A = ""
    B = []
    for i in strng:
        if i != " ":
            A += i
        else:
            if A: # Check A is indeed a valid string
                B.append(A)
                A = ""

    # After iteration is over check A contains a valid string. If so append
    if A:
        B.append(A)
    return(B)
```

Check the commented areas in the code

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a small change in your code. You are adding a string to a list only you find space character. so in the end of string you wont find space character to add.

```
def mysplit(strng):
    A = ""
    B = []
    for i in strng:
            if i != " ":
                    A += i
                    
            else:
                    B.append(A)
                    A = ""
    B.append(A) # Add A when string is completed

    return(B)
```

Or you can maintain the same code, but just change the input string when you get as a parameter

```
strng = strng + ' '
```

Also noticed that you haven't considered the case of multiple spaces in a string.

Comment: awesome! it's so obvious now :)